# How to fix a device not detected through USB in Android, TWRP and Fastboot mode?

Tags: connection-issues, nexus-9

My Android tablet Nexus 9 is not recognized by my laptop. It can be charged, but not be listed by `lsusb` command even in fastboot mode and TWRP. I suppose I accidentally disabled the USB connection through some command as root user.  Is there anyway to check the status of the USB device of Android?

Comment: Have you tried with other USB cables and connecting to other USB ports of PC?

Comment: Yes, and the cable I'm using is no problem with my other android devices.

Comment: You need to remember what command caused the issue, it would be like pulling the needle out of the hay stack for us   .  ... .. It could be caused by missing driver's on your laptop, however other devices work so probably not... ... it could be caused by deleting the files responsible for USB connections.... It could be caused by deleting ADB from `system/bin/adb` .... It could be caused by many things.... Maybe you've rejected the computer connection via ADB on your device ( You'd need to revolk all connections and start ADB again, developer options ) ....  Please try to localize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was physically broken. I replaced usb board, then the problem was fixed.